# Way to fast select text in web page in chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, clipboard, webpage, tts

Anyone knows of a way to select all text in a section of a web page (it woud be a DIV in html) without having to select from top to bottom with the mouse?  The intent is to click at beginning of the text in the main part of the page (no, adds, no menus, etc) to select and send to TTS app
There are ways to do this editing html code, but I am looking for quick select-to-tts (or could be sent to any other app/extension)
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried tripple clicking by chance?

Comment: Thanks, but triple click selects only the current paragraph not all paragraphs in the section

Comment: It would be great if I could ctrl click a word instead of double clicking it to select it. Also when I hold down ctrl, I want to select a number of whole words.

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows 10 Pro version 1903 OS Build 18362.xxx
Chrome Version 75.0.3770.80

1. Ctrl-A = Select All (entire webpage)
2. Ctrl-Shift-End = Select to end from any selected starting point on
   page
3. Ctrl-Shift-Home = Select all from selected starting point to top

Comment: Ctrl-A also works on Windows 8.1 Professional.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I have found which almost answers your Question:

- Select the first word or letter or a part of the word where you want to start
  copying.
- Scroll down till the place you have to copy.
- Hold down the Shift key, and click on the ending of the text.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, I did this for a 30,000-line page where CTRL-A would select stuff unwanted. Your first points in superuser are well deserved, pity it took 4 years!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you may have privacy concern, but this extension might be helpful.
It's called PrintFriendly.
It allows you to do a simple one-click to remove portions yo
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-friendly-pdf/ohlencieiipommannpdfcmfdpjjmeolj

Answer (score 0):

You would love this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-copy/cpckijnniakijaejiimdekjdlnammgko

Only by place the mouse to the paragraph and press ctrl+shirt or ctrl+alt.

Comment: That extension was exactly what I was needed but sadly it got removed from Chrome App Store. I've reuploaded it to github - https://github.com/Andrej730/textcopyext

Answer (score -1):

How do I select all in Chrome on a web page.

Try Ctrl+A
(Ctrl+C to copy, Ctrl+P to paste, Ctrl+Z to undo, Ctrl+Y to "redo (undo an undo) - probably the most useful keyboard shortcuts.)
Edited July 2, 2012 by tengreenfingers

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.